# C# RSA Decryption Issue

Tags: c#, encryption

I tried encrypting connection string on my machine A . It was successful .
I exported the key to some other machine B .It tried to decrypt the web config using that exported key . 
But it failed saying

```
    C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pi "NewEncryptKey
" "C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\NewStuartCN\encryptkeynew.xml"
Importing RSA Keys from file..
Succeeded!

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pa "NewEncryptKey
" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
Adding ACL for access to the RSA Key container...
Succeeded!

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionSt
rings" "C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\NewStuartCN"
Decrypting configuration section...
Failed to decrypt using provider 'NewEncryptProvider'. Error message from the pr
ovider: Not enough storage is available to process this command.
 (C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\NewStuartCN\web.config line 35)

Not enough storage is available to process this command.

Failed!
```

What am I missing here ? 
In my machine B while decrypting I tried

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

aspnet_regiis -pi "NewEncryptKey" "C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\NewStuartCN\encryptkeynew.xml"

aspnet_regiis -pa "NewEncryptKey" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" "C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\NewStuartCN"
```

. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you copy and paste the entire error message here? rather than as a screenshot. makes googling easier.

Comment: Copy the console text and paste it hear inside `<pre> </pre>` tags, don't post  a screenshot. You can highlight the text by going to the `file` menu going to `edit` and choosing `mark`

Comment: Did the same. Looking forward for your help. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the wrong command (`-pdf` instead of `-pd`):

```
aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" "C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\NewStuartCN"
```

should be

```
aspnet_regiis -pd "connectionStrings" "C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\NewStuartCN"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That did not help Sir. -pd requires virtual path which I do not have. I only have the physical path. For that I need to use -pdf option. Any other help ? :(